# How to get data from Firebase in a child?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data structure looks like this:

[image: structure]

Normally there should be multiple users in it, so I got more maps inside the channel ID. I want to retrieve the userID from the first person in that channel ID. When using the correct path to my channel ID, I tried this to retrieve the userID, first following the normal code:

```
let firstChild = UInt(1)

     self.channelRef?.queryLimited(toFirst: firstChild).observeSingleEvent
(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

    })
    if let newCreator = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "userID").value
                            {
                                print(newCreator)
                            }

    let newCreator = value?.["userID"] as! String

    let newCreator = value?["userID"] as? String ?? ""

    if snapshot.key == "userID"
                {
                    let newCreator = snapshot.value as! String
                }
```

Nothing works, mostly the output is just nil. This is a print of snapshot, followed by the print of value:

```
Snap (-KeLAUXw5juT1xBISOLA) {
    "-KeLCHhN3FPZ-chOE9MF" =     {
        PictureVersion = 2;
        readyToGo = 0;
        userID = SZlQ76RLCJQpFa0CDhrgFJoYzrs2;
        username = pietje;
    };
}
Optional({
    "-KeLCHhN3FPZ-chOE9MF" =     {
        PictureVersion = 2;
        readyToGo = 0;
        userID = SZlQ76RLCJQpFa0CDhrgFJoYzrs2;
        username = pietje;
    };
})
```

How to get the userID?

Edit: It seems that the only "key" I get, is the random ID from the user. I need to get data from 1 level deeper I think, but how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let user = value.allValues.first! as! NSDictionary
let userID = user["userID"] as? String ?? ""
```

Though this will crash when there is no user in the snapshot so make sure you write a check for that. It might just be better to do this.

```
self.channelRef?.queryLimited(toFirst: firstChild).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let enumerator = snapshot.children
    while let user = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
        guard let userValue = user.value as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }
        let userID = userValue["userID"] as? String ?? ""
    }
})
```